# Почему блочный элемент игнорирует явно заданную высоту?

Tags: css

Несмотря на явное указание `height: 100%`, `<div>` ведёт себя как при `height: auto`, при том что `width: 100%` работает корректно. Я даже описание свойства `height` перечитал, вдруг я дурак и оно так не работает? Но нет, там написано именно то, что я помню: процентное значение задаёт высоту относительно родительского элемента или экрана. Пробовал явно задать высоту `<body>` - тоже не помогло. Почему так происходит и как теперь сделать высоту во весь экран?

```css
  #startscreen {
  text-align: center;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: gray;
}
#startscreen span {
  vertical-align: bottom;
}
```

```html
<div id="startscreen"><span>Нажмите для продолжения</span></div>
```

Comment: Для произвольного блочного элемента `height` в процентах работать не будет. Если высота внешнего блока вычисляется по содержимому, то высота в % не работает, и заменяется на `height: auto`. Кроме случая, когда у элемента стоит `position: absolute`.

Comment: @Simon интересное кино. Я последние лет пять ничего не верстал, но до того прекрасно растягивал основной блок страницы на весь экран с помощью процентов. Когда это стало так и как теперь это исправлять?

Comment: Это стало лет 20 назад с выходом css 2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для произвольного блочного элемента `height` в процентах работать не будет. Если высота внешнего блока вычисляется по содержимому, то высота в % не работает, и заменяется на `height: auto`. Кроме случая, когда у элемента стоит `position: absolute`.

Оно так происходит вроде как еще со времен спецификации [CSS 2.1](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visudet.html#propdef-height). В Вашем случае можно повесить на парента тоже высоту 100%.

```css
body,
html {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
}

#startscreen {
  text-align: center;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: gray;
}

#startscreen span {
  vertical-align: bottom;
}
```

```html
<div id="startscreen"><span>Нажмите для продолжения</span></div>
```

Comment: Да, я как раз об этом же подумал, проверил и убедился. Похоже я настолько на автомате ставил двум верхним контейнерам 100% всегда, что сам об этом забыл. Ответ принял, спасибо.